# Does setTimeout() really execute in parallel?

Tags: javascript

Consider following JavaScript code:

```
function foo(ary) {
  // some long operation on ary
}
function bar(ary) {
  // some long operation on ary
}
function baz(ary) {
  // some long operation on ary
}

function main(ary) {
  setTimeout(foo, 0, ary);
  setTimeout(bar, 0, ary);
  setTimeout(baz, 0, ary);
}

main([some large array]);
```

From [MDN setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Explanation):

> Code executed by setTimeout() is run in a separate execution context to the function from which it was called.

But does this mean it executes in parallel to any other code that is currently in process?

Considering the example I posted above, assuming a very large array being processed by 3 function, each doing a very long operation on it but are independent of each other, will the 3 functions execute in parallel?

Is there any way on showing the execution of (multiple) `setTimeouts`, maybe using Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: The answers below are correct that this code has absolutely no parallelism going on, but it's worth mentioning that [the Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) is the main way you would go about creating genuine background threads in client-side code.

Comment: Incidentally, the very next sentence on the MDN page you quoted is "As a consequence, the this keyword for the called function will be set to the window (or global) object; it will not be the same as the this value for the function that called setTimeout." which makes it fairly clear that their use of "execution context" was referring to things like the `this` value rather than threads.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  "Execution context" doesn't mean "thread", and until recently Javascript had no support for anything resembling threads.  What actually happens is that an event is pushed onto the event queue that's set to execute in the number of milliseconds specified by the second argument to SetTimeout/SetInterval. The consequence of this is that if you request a 1000ms delay, then 1000ms is the MINIMUM delay you'll get.  If the execution engine is busy doing something else when the 1000ms delay is over then it will have to wait until it's done with what it's doing.

"Execution context" refers to what variable scoping rules are going to apply to the setTimeout callback, meaning that the `this` variable might not be pointing at what you think it will be, etc.

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Thank you. Although all 3 answers are good, and I could only accept 1, I am accepting this answer since the link you posted helped me understand more about timers in JS.

Answer (score 3):

> But does this mean it executes in parallel to any other code that is currently in process?

No, it does not mean that. It will just execute later, when the given time has passed.

Javascript fundamentally does not support multithreading because there are no language facilities to prevent data corruption from simultaneous access nor for having isolated threads communicate via messaging.

A Javascript engine simply processes a queue of events sequentially on a single thread. When the event queue is empty, that thread idles. In a browser, events are added to the queue by user input, page loading, etc. In node.js events can also be HTTP requests or hardware events. And `setTimeout()` simply adds another kind of event with the additional condition that it should only be added to the queue after a certain time has passed.

The "separate execution context" mentioned in the documentation just means that the `this` reference will be different than in the function where `setTimeout()` is called.

Answer (score 3):

By "separate execution context" the doc means in particular that `this` will be different in all likelihood.

In the browser, JavaScript code of one page is always executed in a single thread. Only JavaScript that is run in a separate worker or page can run in parallel.

One reason for this is that JavaScript has direct access to the DOM and getting that to be thread safe would come at significant performance cost. The reasoning is quite similar for nodejs.